# Concrete template body which is there in dll and called in client

Tags: c++

I am calling template method which is there in dll from client and I am trying to understand if dll is linked at linker time then why compiler is not complaining about function body missing or not found in the scope which is called in client. Please look into below code.

```
///Template function body in dll
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T add(T _x,T _y)
{
    return _x +_y;
}

///client code
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ///Calling template method from client
   cout<<add(10,20)<<endl;
}
```

I am trying to understand how compiler finds body for add(10,20) in dll which gets linked during linker time.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand how compiler finds body for add(10,20) in
>   dll which gets linked during linker time.

It doesn't. You'll be surprised to learn that your DLL is completely empty. You see, a template doesn't really exist. It's just a figment of your C++ compiler's fertile imagination.

A template is just, ...a template. It's not real code.

A template only becomes real when it is actually used, or **instantiated**. In this case, your template get instantiated in your `main()`. At this point the template code pops into existence as your compiler actually compiles the code for an ***instance*** of this template with `T=int`, as the template parameter.

Templates, by themselves, are fake and imaginary. You cannot possibly know what "code" they are until you figure out what `T` is (in your case). It could be `int`. It could be `char`. It could be a huge class with hundreds of methods, and an overloaded `+` operator. Each case will result in completely different code.

Having said that: there are compiler-specific ways to instruct the compiler to generate code for a ***particular instance*** of a template. In this case, you can instruct your compiler to produce an instance of `add<int>` and make a DLL out of it. Then your DLL will have real code, but only for `add<int>`, and not `add<double>`, or any other add.

Then, when compiling `main` the compiler will still generate the code for `add<int>`, but at link time the duplicate instance of `add<int>` will get optimized away by the linker, and replaced with the one from the DLL.

Comment: Actually ,the DLL-instances will never be used in the link of the client ,unless they have been exported. Until then all template instanciations will be use non-dll.